# How can we access dynamic variable {{$guid}} inside pre request in postman?

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

I can access guid in url or body like {{$guid}} but same doesn't work inside pre-request script.

Answer (score 1):

actually uuid.v4 represent guid in postman

```
let uuid = require('uuid');
let guid = uuid.v4(); //you can use this variable in wherever you need to use guid in 
                      //pre-request script 
console.log(guid);
```

Comment: Or use `console.log(pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$guid}}'))` 